# Android seekbar two digits after decimals

Tags: android, seekbar

I use a seekbar for my users to set certain amounts they want, right now it only does it by 1.1, 2.2, 3 for example. Is there a way so they can set it like so it could have two decimal places in increments of 5? for example 1.10, 1.15, 1.20, 1.25 (low numbers just for example, amounts range from 0-100 on my seekbar)

```
int currentValue = seekBar.getProgress();
double finalValue = currentValue / 10;

<SeekBar
 android:id="@+id/seekbar"
 android:layout_width="350dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/seekbarTitle"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:max="1000" />
```

Comment: if i understood correctly, you can just change max to 2000 and use finalValue as currentValue / 20. BTW, you need to use 20d instead of 20 to avoid integer division (e.g. 11/10 =1, but 11/10d=1.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a different increment.

```
int currentValue = seekBar.getProgress();
double finalValue = currentValue / 20.0;

<SeekBar
 android:id="@+id/seekbar"
 android:layout_width="350dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/seekbarTitle"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:max="2000" />
```